# Printing decimal precision upto desiired number in cpp

Tags: c++, decimal

I have an application I want to print the precision of the calculated prime number up to the desired number. But the number is omitted on the terminal as shown below.

[image]

The code I used for this is as

```
 int  main ()
{
    cout << "Enter the precision for calculation" << endl;
    long num_steps ;
    cin >> num_steps ;
    cout << "Precision = " << num_steps << endl;

    double step;
    double  x=0.0, pi, sum = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter the number of CPU core involved in calculation" << endl;
    int numberOfCpuCore = 0;
    cin >> numberOfCpuCore;

    int i;

    step = 1.0l/( double) num_steps;


        }
    pi = step * sum;
    printf("Pi value = %.10le\n", pi);
return 0;

}
```

My question is how can I print the precision to the desired number as entered from the command line.

Comment: It _is_ printing the precision you asked for. You are using the `%e` format specifier, so that changes what you see. Since you are using C++, though, you should be using the `setprecision` manipulator or the `format` library instead of `printf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `iomanip`. first add `#include <iomanip>` and then `std::setprecision(num_steps)` like this program:

This code was written based on [Calculate Pi](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calculate-pi-with-python/) from Geeks For Geeks.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
// Initialize denominator
    double  k = 1;

// Initialize sum
    double  s = 0;

    for (auto i(0); i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            s += 4 / k;
        }
        else
        {
            s -= 4 / k;
        }

// denominator is odd
        k += 2;
    }

    cout << "Pi value =" << std::setprecision(k) << s << endl;

// printf("Pi value = %.10le\n", pi);
    return 0;
}
```

**This will be the output:**

[image]

Comment: Please do not display the complete algorithm, as it might cause problem for me. Thanks

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin , Ok I changed it. I changed and use another algorithm that cover and fixed your problem also If another person has your problem too this be useful for him.